# S/MIME Certificate goes to 'Other People' tab in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, smime

When i try to import my S/MIME certificate into my freshly install Mozilla Thunderbird 115.3.2 (64-bit), it goes straight to Other People tab but no Your Certificate tab. This cert is proven to work in Outlook 2017. How to make it appear in Your Certificate tab?

I use DigiCert PKI Platform C2 Shared S/MIME Individual Subscriber CA. my S/MIME common name is my name, is it because of this that it isn't working?

Comment: Two things that I can think of are, did you use the correct format to upload the certificate (including the private one), and do the emails match case-sensitive?

Comment: More specifically, for your own cert you must use PKCS12/P12/PFX format, which contains the cert _and privatekey and chain_. (Most X500DistinguishedName attributes, including commonName, are case-insensitive @not2savvy)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The local part of an email address is case-sensitive as of its RFC, and I’ve seen issues because people weren’t aware of that.

Comment: I did use pfx to import it, which contains all chain, private key and the cert. i happen to look at firefox, the cert is correctly appear in 'Your Certificates' tab. turns out that firefox use Windows Cert Store itself. Knowing that both of them is the product of Mozilla, i ended up change the configuration of Thunderbird to allow read from Win Cert Store. Thanks guys.

Comment: @not2savvy: local-part is allowed (but not recommended) to be case-sensitive in SMTP (821,2821,5321), but NOT in certs; see last two paragraphs of 5280 section 4.1.2.6 and the related security consideration(!) on page 103. (And although 5280 deprecated putting this in Subject, the recent CABforum spec for SMIME certs does allow it, while _requiring_ the better-represented element(s) in SubjectAltName.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the details. While this might technically correct. I have seen cases where certificates where not used because of a case-sensitive mismatch of the email configured in the mail client and the email in the certificate. I don’t remember which mail client that was though.